# Stamp Annotation text and rectangle border displaying wrong when we i try to rotate itext5

Tags: itext

Sample code for create stamp annotation, Stamp Annotation text and rectangle border displaying wrong when we i try to rotate.

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(725 ,192,751,350);
float w = rectangle.getWidth(), h = rectangle.getHeight();
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(page);
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createFreeText(stamper.getWriter(), rectangle, annot.getText(), cb);
boolean baseFont = annot.getAnnotationType().equalsIgnoreCase(AnnotationConstants.AnnotationType.STAMP.name()) ? BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED : BaseFont.EMBEDDED;
PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(w, h);
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(app);
ct.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(w, h));
ct.setIndent(10, true);// 3% of margin
Font textFont = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, baseFont));
textFont.setSize(19);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("Mayank Pandey", textFont);
ct.setText(phrase);
ct.setSpaceCharRatio(400);
ct.go();
app.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
app.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, baseFont), annot.getFontConfiguration().getFontSize());
app.moveText(10, 10);
app.setTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL);
app.setColorFill(new BaseColor(255, 0, 0, 50));
app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
app.rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
app.fillStroke();
annotation.setAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
annotation.setColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);
annotation.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(4, 4, 4));
annotation.setRotate(90);
stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, page);
```

Stamp annotation displaying wrong when rotate pdf

[image: Stamp annotation displaying wrong when rotate pdf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to rotate the content of an annotation by 90°, the content should be created with switched width and height:

```
PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(h, w); //!
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(app);
ct.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(h, w)); //!
...
app.setColorFill(new BaseColor(255, 0, 0, 50));
app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
app.rectangle(0, 0, h, w); //!
app.fillStroke();
```

Comment: @MayankPandey Great! This usually is indicated by accepting the answer (clicking the tick at its upper left).